# Moving my project to a different location broke absolute links

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, url

Before my project was located in the root of domain.com. Most of hrefs are like this:

```
<a href="/user/test">test</a>
```

But since my project was moved to domain.com/catalog/, all of those links are broken, example I posted above leads to:

```
domain.com/user/test
```

instead of

```
domain.com/catalog/user/test
```

What can I do to fix this? Removing "/" from all the urls doesn't sound like a proper solution to me.

Comment: Fix the broken links in your project.  Convert them to relative whenever possible.  When statics are required base them of a CONSTANT defined in a global configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace-all the "/user/test" to "/catalog/user/test" in all the files if that helps, but do this just just for testing with a backup at hand.

But the best way would be chrooting/DefaultRoot(ing) the /catalog/user/ dir and using it for a new alias "/catalog/" on the webserver